# Does QAxServer/ActiveQt support newer versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, activeqt

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-server.html

The "Supported Clients" section in this link suggests that ActiveQt supports "Microsoft Visual Studio.NET/2003". Does this mean that it doesnt support anything newer than that? I am trying to create an ActiveX server using ActiveQt and use it in VS2012. But so far I am out of luck.